Open new PowerShell tabs from ps1 script
I have a ps1 script, in which I open multiple PowerShell windows with different commands on each window using this syntax:
$command = "myCommand"
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-Command `"`$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = '$windowTitle'; Write-Host $myCommand; $myCommand`""

The Start-Process command is being executed multiple times in a for-loop, as well as the command variable is being updated with a new command at each iteration.
The result is multiple PowerShell windows, as one can see here:

Is there any way to open these multiple windows in one window but with multiple tabs like this:

I didn't find a way to do it, and I was wondering whether someone know a way to do it.

Try -NoNewWindow  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4#-nonewwindow

@jdweng it just runs all the commands in the same tab, instead of open new tabs

Have a look at the --window parameter to wt.exe. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows I was able to start a new tab using --window last.

Use wt.exe (the Windows Terminal client) to launch new tabs - use the --window/-w switch with argument 0 to attach the new tab to the window from which the call is made:
wt --window 0 new-tab --profile "Windows PowerShell"



Open PowerShell via WT 3 tabs at once with different commands.

$c = "myCommand"; $P = 'PowerShell'
wt nt $P -c "dir\; pause"`; nt $P -c "Write-Host $c\; pause"`; nt $P -c "Write-Host Hello\; pause"

$c = "myCommand"; $P = 'Windows PowerShell'; $PS = 'powershell.exe'
$AL1 = "-w 0 -p `"$P`" $PS -NoExit -c", "dir"
$AL2 = "-w 0 -p `"$P`" $PS -NoExit -c", "write-host $c"
$AL3 = "-w 0 -p `"$P`" $PS -NoExit -c", "write-host Hello"
Start wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL1
Start wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL2
Start wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL3


run multiple commands at once in one tab

$c = "myCommand"
wt nt PowerShell -c "dir\; Write-Host $c\; Write-Host Hello\; pause"

$c = "myCommand"; $P = 'Windows PowerShell'; $PS = 'powershell.exe'
$AL1 = "-w 0 -p `"$P`" $PS -NoExit -c", "dir\; write-host $c\; write-host Hello"
Start wt.exe -ArgumentList $AL1

